# R package installation - gcc compilation failed (XX can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC)

Tags: r, linux, g++, shared-libraries

I am installing `nloptr` package through R console.

There is a popular question which suggests installing nloptr through apt using `sudo apt-get install libnlopt-dev`. I did try that but no success. If you see the verbose you will find that the setup actually detected the nloptr library `configure: Suitable NLopt library found`.

However, there seems to be this bizzare error that doesn't let me install the library. I even tried installing older versions from tar.gz package but still the same error.

```
> install.packages('nloptr')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/nloptr_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2448313 bytes (2.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘nloptr’ ...
** package ‘nloptr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... yes
configure: Now testing for NLopt header file.
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking nlopt.h usability... yes
checking nlopt.h presence... yes
checking for nlopt.h... yes
configure: Now testing for NLopt versison number.
configure: Suitable NLopt library found.
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating R/PkgFlags.R
** libs
g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c dummy.cpp -o dummy.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init_nloptr.c -o init_nloptr.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c nloptr.c -o nloptr.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o nloptr.so dummy.o init_nloptr.o nloptr.o -L/usr/local/lib -lnlopt -lm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(general.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(optimize.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(mt19937ar.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `mti' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(timer.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `start_inited.4227' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(cdirect.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(pnet.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(crs.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(mlsl.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(ccsa_quadratic.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(mma.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(cobyla.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(newuoa.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(nldrmd.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(sbplx.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(auglag.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(isres.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(slsqp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(esch.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(redblack.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `nil' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(sobolseq.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(DIRect.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/local/lib/libnlopt.a(DIRsubrout.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'nloptr.so' failed
make: *** [nloptr.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nloptr’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/nloptr’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpNXGKfk/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("nloptr") :
  installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
```

**I referred to a lot of SO questions but couldn't figure out what exactly to do. Moreover, the configuration file is infinitely large and I have no clue where to make the changes**

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install r-cran-nloptr`? Should be available on this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u3.5/ (which will work for R 3.5)

Comment: Amazing! Worked like a charm. Thanks
Though I'd still like to know what was the actual issue in the regular installation flow. So will be keeping the question open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JBGruber's comment I found an alternative workaround.

> `sudo apt-get install r-cran-nloptr`